# Converting Analog Reading of Soil moisture to Percentage

Tags: c++, math, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm working on a project wherein my Arduino Uno reads the soil moisture, then sends the data to my Raspberry Pi 3.

I'm using an HL-69 soil moisture detector, which gives off an analog output.
The thing I'm having a problem with is that the sensor gives 1023 when having no contact, 300 when submerged in water.

I want to convert the analog output into Water level percentage, which I am honestly having trouble with.

This is the code that I'm using.

```
int soilPin = A0; 
int tempPin = A1;
int min = 300; //drowned in water
int max = 1000; //dry soil
void setup(){
   Serial.flush();
   pinMode(soilPin,INPUT);
   pinMode(tempPin,INPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
   int sensorValue = analogRead(rainPin);
   int tempData = analogRead(tempPin);
   float percentage = (sensorValue - max)/(min - max);
   double temperature = (double) tempData * (5/10.24);
   Serial.print(",");
   Serial.print(temperature);
   Serial.print(",");
   Serial.println(percentage);
   delay(1000);
}
```

The temperature output is fine (e.g 22.53), but I can't seem to get the water level right.

E.g
Analog Output level is at 300 (Soil is drowning in water);
Display : 100%

I think my percentage formula is off, I just based it off of another SO thread.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an assumption your sensor values **are** between 300 and 1000 then the percentage formula is:

```
float percentage = (float)((sensorValue - min) * 100) / (max - min)
```

If they are not then prior to calculating the percentage you should [map them](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map) to the above range (given that the read sensor values go from 0 - 1023 ) using the code:

```
sensorValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, min, max);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. I have tried the first solution and it outputs a negative number.

I managed to fix it by using the map() function.

`float percentage = map(sensorValue, max, min, 0, 100);`

Thank you for your reply, either way.